# ICINGA2 API Not making host modification

Tags: api, post

i have problem with the API of ICINGA2.

i'm trying to add new variables with the POST call , 
i'm getting the required result,

But ICINGA2 didn't add the new var.

According to documentation:
http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/icinga2-api

With the following API, i creates all our hosts in vienna :

```
curl -k -s -u root:icinga -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT 'https://localhost:5665/v1/objects/hosts/server.example.com' \
-d '{ "templates": [ "generic-host" ], "attrs": { "zone": "Vienna", "address": "180.33.1.123", "check_command": "hostalive", "vars.os" : "Linux", "vars.agent" : "ssh" } }' \
| python -m json.tool
```

While this part works as expected,

The problem is once host created, i need to add various vars for different servers.

for example 
Adding of the variable: "vars.servicename" : "DHCP_Servers"

If i'm going back to the documentation, the below API that will need to be execute:

```
curl -k -s -u root:icinga -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST 'https://localhost:5665/v1/objects/hosts/server.example.com' \
-d '{ "templates": [ "generic-host" ], "attrs": { "zone": "Vienna", "address": "180.33.1.123", "check_command": "hostalive", "vars.os" : "Linux", "vars.agent" : "ssh", "vars.servicename" : "DHCP_Servers" } }' \
| python -m json.tool
```

When i ran the API , as expected i'm getting back:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "code": 200.0,
            "name": "server.example.com",
            "status": "Attributes updated.",
            "type": "Host"
        }
    ]
}
```

**But there is no changes that taking place on ICINGA/ host file.**

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the same user as in my inbox and the forums (https://monitoring-portal.org/index.php?thread/37160-adding-vars-with-api/&postID=234885#post234885) lately. Leaving this as a note here as it might help others to see why it does not work. That feature is just not implemented as it involves storing the applied changes, do a rollback, and re-apply. Not as simple as it sounds.

https://dev.icinga.org/issues/11501

Comment: Comment on this url:
https://dev.icinga.com/issues/11501 > "We know that many of you demand this feature, making a change and then automatically re-evaluate everything. It is not easy to implement with transactions, rollbacks, dependency maps, expressions and so forth. Once we have time estimate and release target, we'll update the issue. If one says - I can do it - please share your findings and patches here for futher review/discussions."